# Installing chrome driver in Circle CI

Tags: linux, bash, selenium-chromedriver, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have the following commands in Circle CI configuration to install chrome driver to run automated test cases.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lsb-release libappindicator3-1
curl -L -o google-chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome.deb
sudo sed -i 's|HERE/chrome"|HERE/chrome" --no-sandbox|g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
rm google-chrome.deb
```

Now this is throwing an error :

```
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease

Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports InRelease

Get:1 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [7340 B]

Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]

Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]

Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports Release.gpg

Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]

Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports Release

Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [829 kB]

Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]

Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages


Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages


Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages


Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages


Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found

Fetched 10.1 MB in 1s (8456 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Exited with code 100
```

so thinking that adding the repo archives will fix the issue, I have added something like this

```
    sudo -i

printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

exit

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lsb-release libappindicator3-1

curl -L -o google-chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome.deb

sudo sed -i 's|HERE/chrome"|HERE/chrome" --no-sandbox|g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

rm google-chrome.deb

exit 0
```

this is again blocking the progress and is showing a shell prompt there in the Circle CI job progress timeline as shown in the image. How can this be fixed ? My only requirement is to install a chrome driver. [image]

Comment: Debian recently archived Jessie; I ran into the same problem a few weeks ago. I tried repairing the repo at the time with alternative sources, but got 404 errors anyway. In the end I bumped up to the latest Debian. Are you using the Docker or Machine executor? Either will let you use a more recent distro version.